# I want to find an ip address using shell script by subtracting dnsdomainname from hostname (hostname - dnsdomainname)?

Tags: hostname, domain-name

I want to find an IP address using shell script by subtracting `dnsdomainname` from `hostname (hostname - dnsdomainname)` ?

Here is what I have

**ip-11-297-183-174.kde.abc.com**

How can i retrieve ip address from the above

Comment: the following >>> `'^ip-(\d{1,3}-\d{1,3}-\d{1,3}-\d{1,3}).+$'` <<< will place the IP address in a capture group.

Comment: can you please explain it

Comment: please see my Answer for some details.

Answer (score 0):

you can replace the unwanted parts with nothing by using regex to capture the IP address in a capture group. then replace the hyphens with dots. like this ...

```
$InString = 'ip-11-297-183-174.kde.abc.com'

$OutString = $InString -replace '^ip-(\d{1,3}-\d{1,3}-\d{1,3}-\d{1,3}).+$', '$1' -replace '-', '.'

$OutString
```

output = `11.297.183.174`